"Advice" — why a uncountable Noun?
Advice means-An opinion or suggestion,then why advice can't be counted??(because opinion or suggestion are of different types which can be countable)

You can count pieces of advice.

@MichaelHarvey what's the difference creates when one use pieces of advice instead of "advice" alone , because advice means "an opinion or suggestion" so should be countable.

Some dictionaries say 'an opinion' or 'a recommendation' in their definitions, but Oxford Languages says "guidance or recommendations offered with regard to prudent future action." It's just a fact that advice is treated as an uncountable noun, unless we specify 'a piece of advice'.

The act of offering or giving an opinion or a suggestion is an example of  advice, but advice is not an opinion per se, or a suggestion per se.

I don't think there is ever much of an answer to "Why?" questions about English.  The answer is "Because that's how English is."

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a law Ed assumption.

I think it should remain open. There is a teachable thing here, folks.


Advice means-An opinion or suggestion,then why advice can't be counted??

The flaw is in your question - "advice" doesn't mean "an opinion". 'Advice' is an uncountable term. It is quantifiable (ie we say "some" advice).
Why is it uncountable? For the same reason that cake can sometimes be uncountable. I might offer you some cake - that's not a specific amount. It could be a big amount or a small amount. But the amount becomes countable when you introduce a unit noun like "slice" or "piece", ie a piece of cake.
Likewise, you can refer to "a piece of advice", but without a unit noun it is uncountable.
So, the difference between "giving advice" and "giving a piece of advice" is the same difference between giving "some cake" and "a piece of cake". The former could be one piece or any number of pieces, the latter is definitely one singular piece.

Then what's the difference between "giving advice & giving a piece of advice"?

@sam the same difference between giving some cake and a piece of cake. The former could be one piece or any number of pieces, the latter is definitely one singular piece. If I gave you a glass of water, I've given you "some water". But if I gave you a glass of water and then a second glass of water, I've still given you "some water".

advice is uncountable, so some advice like some coffee BUT:
We say: Let me give you a piece of advice.
piece of advice
collocation in English
Plenty of examples here: Cambridge Dictionary.
piece of advice makes it countable. Sometimes, you get two pieces of advice:
ludwigguru.com [sign-up required]

He gave us two pieces of advice that I still hold close.
The Guardian - Books

Generally, if it's a lot of advice, we say that: a lot or lots of advice

Then what's the difference between "giving advice & giving a piece of advice"?

@Sam A piece is more specific; Give me some coffee, Give me a cup of coffee.

Can you , please,modify your answer and explain how the both is different in specification?

He gave me advice.vs He gave me a piece of advice

@Sam There is nothing to add. I've explained it. give advice is just general.
